# Jquery-Ui Datepicker already visible when page is loaded, not on click as intended

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I copied the following:

https://codepen.io/saifur0123/pen/KZEaeR

My code looks like this:

```
$(function () {
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({ format: "dd.mm.yyyy" });
});



<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Blubb:</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="filterDate2">

                <!-- Datepicker as text field -->
                <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result looks like this...

[image: The Problem]

I'm sorry but I don't understand why it does not work like in the codepen...
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I was unable to replicate the issue in your codepen.

Comment: It's not my codepen. I just copied it from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it...

I doublechecked everything and found out that not only the library jquery-ui is needed but also bootstrap-datepicker... I totally missed this one the first time... It works now...